# C reverse string function getting weird output

Tags: c

I'm trying to understand pointers and made a reverse string function.
code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *reverseString(char string[]){
    int i;
    int len = strlen(string);
    char reversedString[len];  
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
        reversedString[i] = string[(len - 1) - i];
    }
    printf("%s", reversedString); //print it out

    return reversedString; //return pointer to first element of reversed string
}

int main (){
    char string[6] = "kitten";
    int i;
    char *p = reverseString(string);
    return (0);

}
```

My goal is to reverse the string "kitten" and print the reversed string. I expect the output "nettik" but I get "nettik���". Why am I getting these weird characters?

Comment: Once the `strlen()` problem is fixed, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25603908/stange-behavior-with-my-c-string-reverse-function is another reverse-string question with your other bug (returning a local array).

Comment: The bug here is not the return, even if it is a bug

Comment: @pascx64 Are you saying that returning the local `reversedString` variable is good, safe, well-defined behavior?

Comment: No, this is why is said "even if it is a bug".
It is just, not THE bug that cause the problem of gilianzz

Comment: You are forgetting to place a null-terminator on your new string.

Comment: 1. You are not terminating `reversedString` array with a null-character. 2. You are returning the address of a local array (`reversedString`). 3. I would recommend against using variable-length arrays (VLA); Consider allocating it dynamically instead (`reversedString = malloc(len)`).

Comment: I think the equality of "weird output" and "undefined behavior" should be documented somewhere.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Yep, I see that now. Perhaps you should also recommend to OP against using VLAs (if you agree with that (regardless of the `return` issue)).

Comment: @barakmanos: VLAs can be useful if the arrays are sized big enough.  This one isn't (off by one — forgot the null terminator, which is a problem throughout this code).  You need to be aware of their limitations, and one of those is that there is a limit on the stack size so you should ensure the size is not 'too big' — but there isn't a portable way to do that.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Also not "logically" portable. To C89, and if I'm not mistaken - also to C++.

Comment: @barakmanos: Only in the Windows world is C89 still an issue.  Granted, that's a moderately big hunk of the world, but there are compilers that work with more recent standards than the quarter-century old C89 standard.  You have to decide whether that's a problem for you.  You're right that Standard C++ does not support VLAs.  GCC (G++) does as an extension, but that's not quite the same thing.  Again, you have to make a decision about whether that is critical to you or not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Stop! First of all, you're making a classic mistake beginners often make when they learn about pointers. When you write:

```
char *reverseString(char string[]) {
    ...
    char reversedString[len];
    return reversedString;
}
```

You're returning a pointer to where it *was*, not is: the memory actually gets freed when you leave the function, so there's no guarantee that the memory you think contains your reversed string isn't already getting reused by something else. This way, your program will fail catastrophically.

However, you're printing the reversed string before returning it, so it's no huge problem *yet*. What's going wrong there, then, is that your string isn't properly zero-terminated.

A string in the C language needs room to store its final `'\0'` byte: `char string[6] = "kitten";` is too small to hold the zero-terminated string `{ 'k', 'i', 't', 't', 'e', 'n', '\0' }`. Similarly, when you call `printf("%s", reversedString)`, you haven't properly terminated the string with `'\0'`, so `printf` keeps looking for the end of the string and prints out whatever junk is in memory where `reversedString` is allocated.

You should try:

- making your function return `void`,
- allocating `7` bytes for your original string,
- allocating `strlen(string) + 1` (which will also be 7) bytes for your new string, and
- writing a `'\0'` to the end of your new string after looping through the old one in reverse.

Answer (score 9):

There are at least two major bugs in your code. There could be more.

First, the call to `strlen` causes *undefined behaviour* because you aren't passing it a null-terminated string. The reason for this is that your char array isn't large enough for the null terminator character:

```
char string[6] = "kitten";
```

You need

```
char string[7] = "kitten";
```

or

```
char string[] = "kitten";
```

Second, you are returning a pointer to a local array, namely `reversedString`. De-referencing that would also cause undefined behaviour. You can solve this by wither reversing the string in-place, or passing a pointer to a buffer of the same length as the input. Remember that the reversed string must also be null-terminated.

Comment: Interestingly, the code doesn't dereference the returned pointer-to-local-variable, so that isn't an active problem (but it is a disaster waiting to happen).  Not null-terminating the string in the reverse function (as well as not passing a null-terminated string to a function that expects one) is a problem.  The printing occurs down in the reverse function where the local variable is valid.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, it is a potential problem. If the function is used as expected, UB will ensue even if the null-terminations are fixed. I re-phrased my answer to indicate that it *could* be a problem.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler  I _think_ even copying an invalid pointer is UB.  Certainly de-referencing it is bad.

Comment: @chux: In theory, yes.  In practice, I've not heard of a machine where the assignment in `main()` would cause problems.  Any use of the result could cause problems; possibly even checking the result for nullness could cause problems.  But the systems where that happens are few and far between.  I'm not excusing the returned pointer; it is bad.  I am suggesting that the lack of null terminators, and lack of space in the VLA for a null terminator, are the main problems.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler  I used to think the same thing about signed integer overflow, but then the compilers became "smarter".  I agree with current practice, copying an invalid pointer is is not a great concern but a "disaster waiting to happen".

Answer (score 1):

The function is wrong.

Firts of all it returns pointer to a local array that will be destroyed after exiting the function

```
//,,,
char reversedString[len];  
//...
return reversedString; //return pointer to first element of reversed string
```

Secondly the reversed string shall have terminating zero. However you declare an array that has no space for the terminating zero.

Also this array in main defined incorrectly

```
char string[6] = "kitten";
```

because it does not include terminating zero.

And at last it is a bad design of the function.

If you want to copy the source string in the destination string then the both character arrays should be declared as function parameters. Moreover the source array should be declared as a constant array.

The function can look the following way

```
char *reverseCopyString( char s1[], const char s2[] )
{
    size_t n = strlen( s2 );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) s1[i] = s2[n - i - 1];
    s1[n] = '\0';

    return s1;
}
```

Or you could define the function such a way that ir reverse the source string. For example

```
char *reverseString( char s[] )
{
    size_t n = strlen( s );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n / 2; i++ )
    {
        char c = s[i];
        s[i] = s[n - i - 1];
        s[n - i - 1] = c;
    }        

    return s;
}
```

Take into account that string literals are immutable in C and may not be changed. Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behaviour of the program.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *reverseCopyString( char s1[], const char s2[] )
{
    size_t n = strlen( s2 );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) s1[i] = s2[n - i - 1];
    s1[n] = '\0';

    return s1;
}

char *reverseString( char s[] )
{
    size_t n = strlen( s );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n / 2; i++ )
    {
        char c = s[i];
        s[i] = s[n - i - 1];
        s[n - i - 1] = c;
    }        

    return s;
}

int main( void )
{
    char *s1 = "Hello gilianzz";
    char s2[16];

    puts( s1 );
    puts( reverseCopyString( s2, s1 ) );
    puts( reverseString( s2 ) );
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello gilianzz
zznailig olleH
Hello gilianzz
```